# undefined method `text' for {:text=>"Dashboard", :path=>"/dashboard"}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined an array in one of the helpers in my app that contains one object:

```
module DashboardHelper
    def navigation_data
        [
          {
            text: 'Dashboard',
            path:  dashboard_path
          }
        ]
    end
end
```

When I try to access this in a navigation partial like this:

```
<ul class="nano-content">
    <% navigation_data.each do |link| %>
        <%= link_to link.text, link.path %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

I end up with this error:

```
undefined method `text' for {:text=>"Dashboard", :path=>"/dashboard"}:Hash
```

**what gives?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the error says, you do not have the method `text` defined on `Hash`, but you are calling `link.text`.

it's a hash - use hash notation. `link[:text]`

Comment: it's a hash - use hash notation. `link[:text]`